# Listview gets cut off when translating by y

Tags: android, xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

Note: These are randomly generated addresses

Hey Guys, Learning Xamarin and I am trying to scroll my Frame Layour down and reveal a search bar for my list view. Here is what is happening:

[image: before I translate the listview framelayout]

[image: after translateion]

I color coded my layouts to see if the sizes where a problem, but I dont think they are since my orange layout is plenty big to hold my two entries. Am I using the wrong layouts for this kind of application? I would appreciate any help!

Here is my translation code:

```
frameLayout.Animate().TranslationYBy(editSearch.Height).SetDuration(500).Start();
```

And my layout file:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/swipeLayout">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayoutParent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light">
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="300dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">
                <Button
                    android:text="Add New Address"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/addNewAddress"
                    android:maxHeight="20dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
        <ListView
            android:paddingTop="50dp"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="300dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/myListView"
            android:maxHeight="300dp"/>
    </FrameLayout>
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editSearch"
    android:hint="Search ZipCodes"
    android:textColor="#000"/>
</FrameLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

EDIT:

Here is my OnOptionsItemSelected Code, where my animation is triggered.

```
public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.ItemId)
        {
            case Resource.Id.action_search:
                //search icon has been clicked
                if (isAnimating)
                    return true;
                else
                {
                    if (animateBool)
                    {
                        //list view is up
                        animation anim = new animation(myListView, myListView.Height - editSearch.Height);
                        anim.Duration = 500;
                        myListView.StartAnimation(anim);
                        anim.AnimationStart += Anim_AnimationStartDown; //listener for when animation has started
                        anim.AnimationEnd += Anim_AnimationEndDown;
                        classSwipeRefresh.Animate().TranslationYBy(editSearch.Height).SetDuration(500).Start();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        animation anim = new animation(myListView, myListView.Height + editSearch.Height);
                        anim.Duration = 500;
                        myListView.StartAnimation(anim);
                        anim.AnimationStart += Anim_AnimationStartUp; //listener for when animation has started
                        anim.AnimationEnd += Anim_AnimationEndUp;
                        classSwipeRefresh.Animate().TranslationYBy(-editSearch.Height).SetDuration(500).Start();
                    }
                    animateBool = !animateBool;
                    return true;
                }
            default:
                return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Learning Xamarin and I am trying to scroll my Frame Layour down and reveal a search bar for my list view. Here is what is happening:

I use your code to test, but I have no problem when translating by Y in SwipeRefreshLayout__Refresh event.

```
 public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    string[] items;
    ListView listview1;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swiplayout;
    FrameLayout framelayout;
    EditText edittext;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        listview1 = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.myListView);
        swiplayout = FindViewById<SwipeRefreshLayout>(Resource.Id.swipeLayout);
        framelayout = FindViewById<FrameLayout>(Resource.Id.frameLayout);
        edittext = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editSearch);
        swiplayout.Refresh += Swiplayout_Refresh;
        items = new string[] { "Vegetables", "Fruits", "Flower Buds", "Legumes", "Bulbs", "Tubers" };
        listview1.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, items);
    }

    private void Swiplayout_Refresh(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        framelayout.Animate().TranslationYBy(edittext.Height).SetDuration(500).Start();
    }

  
}
```

This is my screenshot:

[image]

If you want to filter ListView, I suggest you can use SearchView in Toolbar to filter listview data, please take a look this sample:

https://github.com/Cheesebaron/SearchView-Sample/tree/master/SearchViewSample

Comment: Hmm, I put my translation code in my refresh event and it worked perfect just like yours. The error happens when I put it in the `OnOptionsItemSelected` function. its triggered by a button in the action bar. I edited my post with the code for my `OnOptionsItemSelected` function

Comment: something funky with my animation, when I add `editSearch.Animate().AlphaBy(1.0f).SetDuration(500).Start();` in line with my translation it does it fine, might just delete my animate class and do it in the same method as translation

Comment: @mrgucci So you solved your problem now? If  yes, please remember to mark my reply as answer if my reply help you.